# A question about BMO function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an oben bounded subset.
Let $f \in L^1(A)$ be a BMO function, i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{|A|}\int_{A} | f(x) - f_A| dx < \infty
$$
where $|A|$ is the Lebesgue measure of the set |A| and $f_A \colon = \frac{1}{A} \int_A f(y) dy$.

I want to prove that given a subset $B \subset A$, it holds:
$$
\frac{1}{|B|}\int_{B} | f(x) - f_B| dx \le \frac{1}{|A|}\int_{A} | f(x) - f_A| dx.
$$

It should be trivial but I can't prove it.

Comment: Are you sure about the definition of BMO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=[-2,2]$ and $B = [-1,1]$. Take $f = \text{sign}(x)\chi_{[-1,1]}$. Then, $f_A=f_B=0$.
$$\int_A \left\lvert f(x)-f_A\right\rvert = \int_B\left\lvert f(x)-f_B\right\rvert = 2$$
However, as $|A|>|B|$, the inequality you suggested does not hold.